# How to represent Checkers pieces in css?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to build a basic Checkers game with JavaScript. I decided to first do a basic hard-coded layout with HTML and CSS, specifically just to get my CSS classes in order before getting to the logic. I am struggling with implementing the actual Checkers pieces

The way I would like to approach it is to have 2 different classes: 2 x square-{color} and 2 x checker-{color}. I would like to be able to apply checker-{color} on top of square-{color} where the checker is a circle that still has the background of square-{color}

My approach for the circle has been a 50% border radius. 
The code below is not necessarily a good represntation of what I have tried, just what it currently looks like after hours of not being able to come right.

I have tried creating a child element of a square, with the checker-{color} class, but it throws my spacing out completely, and I would prefer avoiding this approach and rather do it as I described above (if it is possible)

```css
.square_black, .square_white {
  width:72px;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  float: left;
  margin:0.06px;
}

.square_black{
  background: #11141d;
}

.square_white {
  background: #ad724d;
}

#container{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.checker_blue {
  background: darkblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:100%;
  padding:100%;

}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
    <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
    <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
    <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe out of subject, but here is a chess with its pieces , that you can also drag & drop :) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRKrrbN , if that gives you some idea (remake of a 8years old dabblet of mine) it uses a table which is fine for that case.

Comment: a checker piece could be written in html `&circledcirc;` **⊚**  see eventually https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo element with `.checker-{color}` to avoid creating an extra element disable the padding to avoid the extra space:

```css
.square_black,
.square_white {
  width: 72px;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  float: left;
}

.square_black {
  background: #11141d;
}

.square_white {
  background: #ad724d;
}

#container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.checker-blue {
  padding: 0;
}

.checker-blue:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: darkblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to consider multiple background and you will have less of code. The trick is to have a circle with transparent color and you simply change the color using a variable.

Adjust the percentage value of the gradient if you don't want the circle to cover all the area:

```css
.square_black,
.square_white {
  width: 72px;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  float: left;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c,transparent) 98%,transparent 100%),
   var(--b,transparent);
}

.square_black {
   --b:#11141d
}

.square_white {
   --b:#ad724d;
}

#container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.checker-blue {
  --c: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
  <div class='square_black checker-blue'></div>
  <div class='square_white'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.square_black, .square_white {
  width:72px;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  float: left;
  margin:0.06px;
  position: relative;
}

.square_black{
  background: #11141d;
}

.square_white {
  background: #ad724d;
}

#container{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.checker_blue:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: darkblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;

}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    <div class='square_black checker_blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
    <div class='square_black checker_blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
    <div class='square_black checker_blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
    <div class='square_black checker_blue'></div>
    <div class='square_white'></div>
</div>
```